# How to complete the forecast line using plot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, forecasting

I have been working on a script in R that will predict a number.

```
# Load Forecast library
library(forecast)

# Load dataset
bwi <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/nsoria/Downloads/AMS Globales/TEC_BWI.csv", header=TRUE, sep=';', dec=",")

# Create time series starting in January 2015
ts_bwi <- ts(bwi$BWI, frequency = 12, start = c(2015,1))

# Pull out the seasonal, trend, and irregular components from the time series 
model <- stl(ts_bwi, s.window = "periodic")

# Predict the next 5 months of SLA
pred <- forecast(model, h = 5)

# Plot the results
plot(pronostico)
```

This output gives this

[image: plot]

Somehow, the forecasted line is not linked with the actual values.

Question: How can I make the line linked from the last known value to the first forecasted value?

Edit 01/01: Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N_AeOemt1lmO4GO8eVQmKDH8VtaF_Kya) where the CSV is located to reproduce the case.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't have your data. `pronostico` is not in the question. The question itself is not reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. I have uploaded the file to my Google Drive account and posted the link in the main question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your real time series to the predicted one like in the code below

```
pred_mod<-pred
ts_real<-pred$x
pred_mod$x<-ts(c(ts_real,pred$mean),frequency=12,start=c(2015,1))
plot(pred_mod)
```

[here the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5pAT.jpg)